# Is it possible to secure api by using oauth protocol by my logic to create clientid and generate access token?

Tags: rest, spring-security, oauth-2.0

Is it possible to secure api by using oauth protocol by my logic to create clientid and generate access token?

As per below spring-security.xml token will be generated automatically but I want to use clientid and access token for this clientid (available in db) for implementing auth in api.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2" 
xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

<!-- Just for testing... -->
<http pattern="/oauth/cache_approvals" security="none" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" />
<http pattern="/oauth/uncache_approvals" security="none" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" />

<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request parameters -->
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<!-- The OAuth2 protected resources are separated out into their own block so we can deal with authorization and error handling 
    separately. This isn't mandatory, but it makes it easier to control the behaviour. -->
<http pattern="/test/*" create-session="never" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/test/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="test" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="test/client" />
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</authentication-manager>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service id="userDetailsService">
            <user name="user" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<bean id="clientDetailsUserService" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<!-- Used for the persistenceof tokens (currently an in memory implementation) -->
<bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore" />

<!-- Used to create token and and every thing about them except for their persistence that is reposibility of TokenStore (Given here is a           default implementation) -->
<bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<bean id="userApprovalHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler">
    <property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices" />
</bean>

<!-- authorization-server aka AuthorizationServerTokenServices is an interface that defines everything necessary for token management -->
<oauth:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
    user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
    <oauth:authorization-code />
    <oauth:implicit />
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:client-credentials />
    <oauth:password />
</oauth:authorization-server>

<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter" resource-id="test" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />
<!-- ClientsDeailsService: Entry Point to clients database (given is in memory implementation) -->
<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
<!-- client -->
<oauth:client client-id="the_client" authorized-grant-types="authorization_code,client_credentials"
        authorities="ROLE_USER" scope="read,write,trust" secret="secret" />

<oauth:client client-id="my-trusted-client-with-secret" authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit"
        secret="somesecret" authorities="ROLE_USER" />

</oauth:client-details-service>

<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
    <!--you could also wire in the expression handler up at the layer of the http filters. See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1452 -->
    <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
</sec:global-method-security>

<oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />

<oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using

```
 <oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
<oauth:client client-id="the_client" authorized-grant-types="authorization_code,client_credentials" authorities="ROLE_USER"          scope="read,write,trust" secret="secret" />
<oauth:client client-id="my-trusted-client-with-secret" authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit"
    secret="somesecret" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
```

Use this

```
<beans:bean id="clientDetails"  class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.JdbcClientDetailsService">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</beans:bean>
```

Also you can create your own custom ClientDetailsService like JdbcClientDetailsService provided by spring-oauth.

Note:- When using JdbcClientDetailsService  make oauth-client-details table with necessary column which is used by JdbcClientDetailsService.

Comment: So the million-dollar question is, what is the DDL for that table? I can't seem to find it anywhere...

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/test/resources/schema.sql